# CSS flex div image to the right

Tags: html, image, css, flexbox

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
.div1 {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="div1">
    123<br>456<br>789
    <img src="smiley.gif">
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I use this code to make a flex `div`. There is some text on the left and an image to the right. I use `align-items: flex-start;` so that the image doesn't stretch. Code works good but is there a way to move the image always to the bottom right of the div? Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this CSS rule would accomplish that

```
.div1 img {
    margin-left: auto;         /*  push it to right  */
    align-self: flex-end;      /*  push it to bottom  */
}
```

Stack snippet

```css
.div1 {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.div1 img {
    margin-left: auto;
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
    123<br>456<br>789<br>
    123<br>456<br>789
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50/f00">
</div>
```